# Read a large compressed CSV file and aggregate/process rows by field

Tags: python, csv

I have as input a potentially large CSV file (gzip compressed) with a known structure. I don't know in advance the size of this file, but let's say it can't fit in memory. The rows in this CSV are ordered like the following:

```
key1, …other fields
key1,
key1,
key1,
key2,
key2,
key3,
key4,
key4,
⋮
```

They are ordered by the value in the first column (let's call it `key`), but it is unknown how many rows are there for each distinct key.  I need to scan the whole file and process only the first N rows matching each key (there could be more than N rows for some of the keys). These N rows per key can be processed in memory.

I came up with this code, but I don't like it very much. It is a bit messy:

```py
import gzip


def process_rows(key rows):    
    print(f'Processed rows for key {key}')


def main(file_path, N=1000):    
    with gzip.GzipFile(filename=file_path) as file:
        curr_key = None
        rows_to_process = []

        for line in file:
            line = line.decode().strip()

            if len(line) == 0:
                continue

            fields = line.split(',')
            [key, field2, field3] = fields

            if curr_key is not None:
                if curr_key != key or (len(rows_to_process) > 0 and len(rows_to_process) % N == 0):                    
                    process_rows(key, rows_to_process)

                    # Find next key if needed
                    while curr_key == key:
                        line = next(file, None)

                        if line is None:
                            return  # End of file, exit

                        line = line.decode().strip()

                        if len(line) < 1:
                            continue

                        fields = line.split(',')
                        [key, field2, field3] = fields

                    print('Found next key', key)

                    # Reset rows to process
                    rows_to_process = []

            curr_key = key
            rows_to_process.append([key, field2, field3])

        # Flush trailing data
        if (len(rows_to_process) > 0):
            process_rows(key, rows_to_process)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Minor niggles

Testing `len() > 0` is over-wordy.  If we want to test whether a string or list is non-empty, its truthiness directly indicates that (see below, `if not line:`).

---

## Structure and design

There's a lot in `main()`, and it doesn't lend itself to unit-testing very well.  I would split its responsibilities, probably splitting into a generator that emits each line as an array (or more likely, a tuple) of fields, and a consumer that batches your N rows:

```
def rows(input):
    '''
    Generator function yielding the first three fields of each line of input.
    '''
    for line in input:
        line = line.decode().strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        fields = line.split(',') # assumes no quoted ',' in fields
        yield fields[0:2]
```

For the grouping of up to N lines, we can take advantage of the standard library functions in `itertools` to eliminate most of the logic you wrote.

Specifically, [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get an iterator for each group of rows, and [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to take the first N elements from each of those:

```
import gzip
import itertools
import operator

def main(file_path, N=1000, func=process_rows):
    groups = itertools.groupby(rows(gzip.GzipFile(filename=file_path)),
                               operator.itemgetter(0))
    for (key, values) in groups:
        func(key, itertools.islice(values, N))
```

---

I tested the code with a modified process function:

```
def process_rows(key, rows):    
    print(f'Processed {len(list(rows))} row(s) for key {key}')
```

and this input:

```
alpha,0,1
alpha,0,2
alpha,0,3
alpha,1,4
beta,2,6
gamma,3,0
gamma,4,0
gamma,5,0
gamma,6,0
```

The output is:

```
Processed 3 row(s) for key alpha
Processed 1 row(s) for key beta
Processed 3 row(s) for key gamma
```

Comment: _Testing len() > 0_ might also be considered good PEP0020 (explicit is better than implicit).